# I've always thought soybean yogurt <is><was> good for health

Tags: tense

(1) I've always thought soybean yogurt **is** good for health.

(2) I've always thought soybean yogurt **was** good for health.

**Question:** Which sentence is correct?

I assume:

(a) Both sentences are correct.

and

(b) Only (1) implies that the speaker still thinks that soybean yogurt is good for health.

**[Edit]** The sentence "What you painted is/was great!" in [Lambie's suggested thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143540/what-tense-should-i-use-here-what-you-painted-is-was-great) does not use the present perfect or the adverb *always*.

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times. the yogurt was then, or the yogurt is good for your health is a truism, regardless of the tense of the verb. I have always thought that he is/was my friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What tense should I use here? What you painted is/was great!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143540/what-tense-should-i-use-here-what-you-painted-is-was-great) Look at Gary's answer.

Comment: @Lambie.You are wrong. "The yogurt is good for your health" is NOT a truism. Yogurt is **bad** for the health of many Japanese people.

Comment: You are missing the main point. If you say IS, it means a general thing that is still true; if you say WAS, it either applied to you THEN, or is not true any longer. Anyway, for Japan, just add soybean. "He said he IS my friend" continues to be true now. "He said he was my friend" is not true now.

Comment: @Lambie for reported speech in the past it's standard to use the past tense regardless.  "He said he was my friend" does not by itself imply a change of heart.

Comment: @phoog No, both "He said the yogurt is good for me" or "was good for me." are both right. " Last week I *found out* Peter *is* married". "is" can be used instead of "was". An ongoing state or condition: See this answer on ELU. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249667/present-past-tense-in-a-subordinate-clause

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the argument about logic, and focusing on how real people actually speak, we see that it is very common to use the past tense. Of course context is important (maybe that should be the subtitle of this SE site).

Imagine a business owner’s being questioned by law enforcement about his partner. He could perfectly acceptably say, “I have always thought he **acted** in the firm’s best interest,” even when the owner’s belief continues to the moment of his utterance. If instead of *have always thought*, he used *believe*, then *acted* would become present: *I believe he acts*. And of course, if forensic accountants later present incontrovertible evidence that the partner was embezzling, then the tense of the main verb might morph to “I **had** always thought.”

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul Tanenbaum. I've edited my post.

Comment: I think he liked me. I think he likes me. One was true and the other continues the state or condition of liking.

Comment: @Lambie the construction in question uses the present perfect in the main clause, not the present indicative.

Comment: @phoog Yes. The reason that I started this thread is that my sentences use the present perfect, not the present simple, in the main clause.

Answer (score 1):

There are nuances here, but I think sentence #1 is better.

I think it will help to break down the sentence into its grammatical parts. The second half of the sentence "...soybean yogurt is good for health" is called a [noun clause, which here is serving as a direct object](https://linguisticsgirl.com/using-noun-clauses-as-direct-objects/) of the transitive verb "thought."

Also note, sometimes in English we have an unspoken word "that". To make things more complex, we have an unspoken word "that" linking the clauses: "I always thought..." that "...yogurt is good for health." [The word "that" can be omitted in phrases about talking or thinking, as is the case here.](https://myenglishgrammar.com/lessons/that-clauses/)

*I've always thought* is a use of [the *present perfect tense*, which implies that the action has happened in the past, and is still probably ongoing.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/) Since you are hinting that this feeling is ongoing, I would use sentence #1. Since the speaker is still probably thinking this way, sentence #1 is better.

If you would like to emphasize that you no longer think this way, you may want to change to a simpler verb form. Try: *I always thought soybean yogurt was good for health.* However, for this, I might change the word "always" to a different phrase, because evidently you changed your mind at some time, so it's not "always." Perhaps try: *For a long time, I thought soybean yogurt was good for health.*

All that being said, if you said to me *I've always thought soybean yogurt was good for health.* I would not question it, and would mostly understand through context. I would believe that you thought that in the past, but I might need clarification about whether you now think that way or not. Also, you were using spoken English or informally on the Internet, I would suggest adding the possessive adjective "your" to modify "health." *I've always thought soybean yogurt was good for your health.* In a formal written context, I would probably write: *I have always thought soybean yogurt was good for one's health.*